# Multiple file (deletion of same string from begining and ending rows)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a multiple files. Every file have a format which is shown below:

```
<float> <int> <stringSAME>
<float> <int> <stringSAME>
<float> <int> <string>
......
<float> <int> <stringSAME>
......
......
<float> <int> <string>
<float> <int> <stringSAME>
<float> <int> <stringSAME>
```

Here the strings present at the 1st and 2nd line are same where as the strings present at the last few line are also same. It is denoted as stringSAME. Now I want to delete this stringSame from the beginning and end of the files. But KEEPING in between stringSame intact. This procedure is to carried out for multiple files having the same format.
Please suggest some solution to tackle it. I am using python as my programming language.

Comment: Did you want to remove the whole line or just the `<stringSAME>` part?

Comment: yes i want remove the whole line!

Comment: So for any line in the file that ends with `<stringSAME>` we want to remove that line? That's easy, but I want to make sure we're on the same page.

Comment: yes! these are present in the same file

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do this, depending on how you want to use it afterwards.

If you're just trying to use the lines as DATA, we can do:

```
with open("path/to/file") as f:
    data = (line for line in f if not line.endswith("<stringSAME>"))
```

If you need the file itself to change, I'd consider overwriting it after this.

```
with open("path/to/file","w") as f: 
    # opening in "w" mode BLANKS the file, so make sure
    # that you've saved that original data somewhere
    for line in data:
        f.write(line+"\n")
```

You could also write it to a new copy of the file:

```
with open("path/to/sanitized_file","w") as f:
    for line in data:
        f.write(line+"\n")
```

If you're trying to do this on multiple files, build a list first.

```
import os

list_of_files = ["file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt"]
for file in list_of_files:
    in_file = os.path.join("path","to",file)
    out_file = os.path.join("path","to","post proc",file)

# if you have to do it to a whole directory worth of files, try this instead
## import glob
## list_of_files = glob.glob("path/to/dir/*")
## for file in list_of_files:
##     in_file = file
##     head,tail = os.path.split(file)
##     out_file = os.path.join(head,"post proc",tail)
# which simplifies a lot of the following, since none of the FileNotFoundErrors
# should ever trigger, other than the one in case the post proc directory
# doesn't exist

    try:
        with open(in_file, 'r') as f:
            data = (line for line in f if not line.endswith("<stringSAME>"))
    except IOError as e:
        # log and handle error if you can't open file
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        # log and handle error if the file isn't there
    try:
        with open(out_file,'w') as f:
            for line in data:
                f.write(line+"\n")
    except IOError as e:
        # log and handle error if you can't write to file
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        # log and handle error if the directory doesn't exist
```

Comment: the above code is not workingValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: @U-571 check your indentation. `f` is only open inside the `with` block, so if you've got your indentation off by one, you'll try and read (or write to) `f` after it's been closed.